# JNDI naming with websphere 7

Tags: websphere, websphere-7

I have an application that uses EJB and JPA2.0 with eclipselink. I have been able to deploy it successfully and the application starts successfully but when i try to access the uri of the webservice i keep getting different errors depending on what i do.

Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.5" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<servlet>
<servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<persistence-context-ref>
    <persistence-context-ref-name>persistence/BACPOnline5PU</persistence-context-ref-name>
    <persistence-unit-name>BACPOnline5PU</persistence-unit-name>
    </persistence-context-ref>
    <resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>UserTransaction</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.transaction.UserTransaction</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

And my persistence.xml is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="BACPOnline5PU" transaction-type="JTA">  <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<jta-data-source>jdbc/infopool</jta-data-source>
<properties/>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I have a PersistenceService class that i use to create persistence from my webservices.
i create my lookup like this

```
private PersistenceService() { 
    try {
    this.em = (javax.persistence.EntityManager) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/persistence/BACPOnline5PU");
    this.utx = (UserTransaction) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
    }
```

I get the error below.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ibm.websphere.naming.CannotInstantiateObjectException: Exception occurred while the JNDI NamingManager was processing a javax.naming.Reference object. [Root exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory has not been created for PU : PuId=BACPOnline5_war#BACPOnline5.war#BACPOnline5PU]
    at com.tavia.service.PersistenceService.<init>(PersistenceService.java:49)
    at com.tavia.service.PersistenceService.<init>(PersistenceService.java:21)
    at com.tavia.service.PersistenceService$1.initialValue(PersistenceService.java:31)
    at com.tavia.service.PersistenceService$1.initialValue(PersistenceService.java:28)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:152)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:142)
    at com.tavia.service.PersistenceService.getInstance(PersistenceService.java:59)
    at com.tavia.service.GltmMisCodesResource.get(GltmMisCodesResource.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:149)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:67)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:259)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:83)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:133)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:71)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:990)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:941)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:932)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:384)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:451)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:632)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3935)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.naming.CannotInstantiateObjectException: Exception occurred while the JNDI NamingManager was processing a javax.naming.Reference object. [Root exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory has not been created for PU : PuId=BACPOnline5_war#BACPOnline5.war#BACPOnline5PU]
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.Helpers.processSerializedObjectForLookupExt(Helpers.java:1033)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.urlbase.UrlContextHelper.processBoundObjectForLookup(UrlContextHelper.java:179)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.processBoundObjectForLookup(javaURLContextRoot.java:408)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.urlbase.UrlContextImpl.lookup(UrlContextImpl.java:1249)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextImpl.lookup(javaURLContextImpl.java:395)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookup(javaURLContextRoot.java:220)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookup(javaURLContextRoot.java:160)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:436)
    at com.tavia.service.PersistenceService.<init>(PersistenceService.java:46)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory has not been created for PU : PuId=BACPOnline5_war#BACPOnline5.war#BACPOnline5PU
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPUnitInfo.getEntityManagerFactory(JPAPUnitInfo.java:1390)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPUnitInfo.getEntityManagerPool(JPAPUnitInfo.java:1673)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPATxEntityManager.<init>(JPATxEntityManager.java:160)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAComponentImpl.getEntityManager(JPAComponentImpl.java:1043)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.JPAJndiLookupObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(JPAJndiLookupObjectFactory.java:151)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstanceByFactoryInReference(NamingManager.java:485)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:350)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.Helpers.processSerializedObjectForLookupExt(Helpers.java:927)
    ... 55 more

[10/12/11 12:37:20:693 CEST] 00000014 servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet ServletAdaptor in application BACPOnline5_war. Exception created : java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ibm.websphere.naming.CannotInstantiateObjectException: Exception occurred while the JNDI NamingManager was processing a javax.naming.Reference object. [Root exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory has not been created for PU : PuId=BACPOnline5_war#BACPOnline5.war#BACPOnline5PU]
    at com.tavia.service.PersistenceService.<init>(PersistenceService.java:49)
    at com.tavia.service.PersistenceService.<init>(PersistenceService.java:21)
    at com.tavia.service.PersistenceService$1.initialValue(PersistenceService.java:31)
    at com.tavia.service.PersistenceService$1.initialValue(PersistenceService.java:28)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:152)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:142)
    at com.tavia.service.PersistenceService.getInstance(PersistenceService.java:59)
    at com.tavia.service.GltmMisCodesResource.get(GltmMisCodesResource.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:149)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:67)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:259)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:83)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:133)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:71)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:990)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:941)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:932)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:384)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:451)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:632)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3935)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.naming.CannotInstantiateObjectException: Exception occurred while the JNDI NamingManager was processing a javax.naming.Reference object. [Root exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory has not been created for PU : PuId=BACPOnline5_war#BACPOnline5.war#BACPOnline5PU]
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.Helpers.processSerializedObjectForLookupExt(Helpers.java:1033)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.urlbase.UrlContextHelper.processBoundObjectForLookup(UrlContextHelper.java:179)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.processBoundObjectForLookup(javaURLContextRoot.java:408)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.urlbase.UrlContextImpl.lookup(UrlContextImpl.java:1249)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextImpl.lookup(javaURLContextImpl.java:395)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookup(javaURLContextRoot.java:220)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookup(javaURLContextRoot.java:160)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:436)
    at com.tavia.service.PersistenceService.<init>(PersistenceService.java:46)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory has not been created for PU : PuId=BACPOnline5_war#BACPOnline5.war#BACPOnline5PU
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPUnitInfo.getEntityManagerFactory(JPAPUnitInfo.java:1390)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPUnitInfo.getEntityManagerPool(JPAPUnitInfo.java:1673)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPATxEntityManager.<init>(JPATxEntityManager.java:160)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAComponentImpl.getEntityManager(JPAComponentImpl.java:1043)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.JPAJndiLookupObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(JPAJndiLookupObjectFactory.java:151)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstanceByFactoryInReference(NamingManager.java:485)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:350)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.Helpers.processSerializedObjectForLookupExt(Helpers.java:927)
    ... 55 more

[10/12/11 12:37:20:693 CEST] 00000014 LocalTranCoor E   WLTC0017E: Resources rolled back due to setRollbackOnly() being called.
[10/12/11 12:37:20:709 CEST] 00000014 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[ServletAdaptor]: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ibm.websphere.naming.CannotInstantiateObjectException: Exception occurred while the JNDI NamingManager was processing a javax.naming.Reference object. [Root exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory has not been created for PU : PuId=BACPOnline5_war#BACPOnline5.war#BACPOnline5PU]
    at com.tavia.service.PersistenceService.<init>(PersistenceService.java:49)
    at com.tavia.service.PersistenceService.<init>(PersistenceService.java:21)
    at com.tavia.service.PersistenceService$1.initialValue(PersistenceService.java:31)
    at com.tavia.service.PersistenceService$1.initialValue(PersistenceService.java:28)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:152)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:142)
    at com.tavia.service.PersistenceService.getInstance(PersistenceService.java:59)
    at com.tavia.service.GltmMisCodesResource.get(GltmMisCodesResource.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:149)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:67)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:259)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:83)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:133)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:71)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:990)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:941)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:932)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:384)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:451)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:632)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3935)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.naming.CannotInstantiateObjectException: Exception occurred while the JNDI NamingManager was processing a javax.naming.Reference object. [Root exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory has not been created for PU : PuId=BACPOnline5_war#BACPOnline5.war#BACPOnline5PU]
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.Helpers.processSerializedObjectForLookupExt(Helpers.java:1033)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.urlbase.UrlContextHelper.processBoundObjectForLookup(UrlContextHelper.java:179)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.processBoundObjectForLookup(javaURLContextRoot.java:408)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.urlbase.UrlContextImpl.lookup(UrlContextImpl.java:1249)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextImpl.lookup(javaURLContextImpl.java:395)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookup(javaURLContextRoot.java:220)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookup(javaURLContextRoot.java:160)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:436)
    at com.tavia.service.PersistenceService.<init>(PersistenceService.java:46)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory has not been created for PU : PuId=BACPOnline5_war#BACPOnline5.war#BACPOnline5PU
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPUnitInfo.getEntityManagerFactory(JPAPUnitInfo.java:1390)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPUnitInfo.getEntityManagerPool(JPAPUnitInfo.java:1673)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPATxEntityManager.<init>(JPATxEntityManager.java:160)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAComponentImpl.getEntityManager(JPAComponentImpl.java:1043)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.JPAJndiLookupObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(JPAJndiLookupObjectFactory.java:151)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstanceByFactoryInReference(NamingManager.java:485)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:350)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.Helpers.processSerializedObjectForLookupExt(Helpers.java:927)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend create datasource in websphere and map to reference in web.xml

### web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/datasource</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

And use reference in persistence.xml

### persistence.xml

```
<jta-data-source> java:comp/env/jdbc/datasource</jta-data-source>
```

During deployment process you shoud map reference 'jdbc/datasource' to real datasource.